# How can I theme a form element with hook_preprocess_form_element()?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have an exposed form in a D8 view which includes several fields, output through form-element.html.twig (amongst others). I added a function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
...
}
```

This contains an 'element' key and I could add a class in there, BUT I see no way of identifying which form this is part of. The 'element' has a child '#parents' but this is simply the name of the field.

The whole point of this is to add some Bootstrap responsive classes to these different form items for layout. I tried `template_preprocess_form` and while I see the fields listed as elements, I don't see a way to add classes to the form element label.

What is best practice for theming D8 exposed forms?

Update: I used XDebug with PhpStorm to debug both `MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element` and `MYTHEME_preprocess_form` and explored the entire tree of `$variables` but could see nothing hinting at parent form ID or similar.

Comment: You are on the right track, if you use `kint($variables);`, you should be able to see what is in the array.  I have done this to alter form elements, change the label order, add classes and such. For the exposed form, there might be a different theme hook which should show up in twig debug.

Comment: @Danny Englander, do you have an example how to find the parent form of a form element?

Comment: @4k4, Not offhand for that specific thing, just throwing around some ideas here.

Comment: Was at the same point as Nic some time ago, gave up on theming and used form build/alter for the bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 2):

As @4k4 said, if all you want is to add some classes, then use `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. `$form['your_element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'your-class` is all you need.

I'm pretty sure that single form elements don't have the form ID stored somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to be able to change the label HTML node also (with some CSS classes) but doesn't seem available in `$form` in `hook_form_alter`

Comment: Then combine it. Add a class to the form element through form alter, then based on having that class (or any other thing, really), add that or another class to the $variables['label']

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a class to the label, you can write your own `form-element-label.html.twig`.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about that. But I want it only to affect this exposed filter on this view.