# Is there a way to provide theme name suggestion for form elements?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I'm trying to look for a way to modify the markup for a form element without touching the default theme/template. Upon checking the source code, Drupal does not seem to recommend any theme suggestions for editing form elements. I have multiple views using the same field on the exposed filter. If I try to edit the form-element-label.html.twig it will affect all of the elements with the same field.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/iom/templates/layout/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
<label for="edit-field-themes-target-id" class="label">Themes</label>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/iom/templates/layout/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
```

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211271/how-can-i-theme-a-form-element-with-hook-preprocess-form-element and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226491/change-a-normal-submit-input-type-to-button-type-with-button-tag

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have to implement two hooks. One to add the suggestion, and one to define a template. [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) and [`template_preprocess_form_element`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/template_preprocess_form_element/8.2.x) (aka `hook_preprocess_HOOK`).

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() == '/user/login') {
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '--user-login';
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_form_element().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element(&$variables, $hook, &$info) {
  $info['template'] = 'form-element--user-login';
}
```

---

Source: [Form element template suggestion has no effect](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2944110).

Comment: Hello, apologies for my ignorance. Lets say I have a view with an exposed filter. Is it possible to only target the form elements of a specific view? I'm trying to understand the answer you have suggested. Still new with drupal hooks. Let's say I want to create a theme suggestion for a `form-element` that has a `label` and `select` element

Comment: @clestcruz – You have to wrap the code inside the hooks with some `if` conditions to fire only according your logic. Check what's inside `$variables`, maybe there's something you can identify your view with. As last resort you can also check the current URL.